# Why has my jasmine plant gone dry suddenly

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

I bought my jasmine plant two weeks ago. Initially it looked very healthy and smelt great. Now it has completely dried up. I have cut a lot of the dead parts off. But what should I do to keep it alive?

[image]

Comment: have you watered it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to know more about where you bought this Jasmine - if it was indoors in the houseplant section of a garden centre or a supermarket, then it's likely *Jasminum polyanthemum*, which is not fully hardy outdoors in the UK and is sold as a temporary, flowering houseplant whilst it is actually in bloom. Other,similar Jasmines are intended to be planted outdoors, but given the time of year and the fact this one has been forced into flower, I'll  assume it is *J. polyanthemum*, although it's usually sold grown round a hoop shaped support rather than up three sticks.

Although it might be sold as a houseplant, it actually isn't too keen on hot room temperatures, so the best place to put it indoors is in a cool room, well away from heat sources, in a brightly lit spot, like next to a window. It is also extremely important to keep them well watered, though not waterlogged - they should be kept slightly moist whilst in flower, but not left sitting in water in any outer tray or pot. I can't tell if yours is in a pot with drainage holes; if it isn't, it should be. The likelihood is you've had it in a room that's overly warm and not kept it sufficiently watered, and that's why it has shrivelled up.

These are usually just temporary visitors to the home - they inevitably run out of root  room in their pots rather quickly (planted outdoors, they will get up to 35 feet tall), so they are often discarded once flowering is over. Given you're in London, if you  have somewhere like a south facing wall or fence which is quite   sheltered outdoors, you can try to keep it alive until the weather warms up towards the end of May, harden it off, then plant it outdoors. If you have such a sheltered spot for it, it will survive most of the winters we get here these days, but in a hard winter, it will be killed.

If you want to try to keep it going, move it to a cool room and keep it well watered - other than buds which are already present, it is unlikely to produce any more flowers for some months though. Further info here https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just been potted up before sale. Grab a teaspoon, and gently excavate at the edge. If you find the digging easy with no roots, then it has just been potted up. Treat as Bamboo suggests. If it dies totally, do a post-mortem on the roots.